# Show that $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ design with $v\leq k+t$ is trivial

Tags: combinatorial-designs

Let $D=(V,B)$ be a $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ design where $V$ is a finite set and $B$ is a collection of subsets of $V$. A trivial $t$-design is defined as a design with one block that contains all the points or a design that has all the $k$-subsets of the set. When $t=0$, $D$ is trivial. I set $t>0$, and then I tried to show that the number of blocks is $n \choose k$. It seems that I need to approach in other way.

Comment: The number of blocks of $t$-design is $\lambda {v\choose t}\over {k \choose t}$. I tried with this identity.

Comment: This is quite an interesting problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Not yet. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ideas: yes. Solution: no (see my answer below).

Comment: Update: I now have a proof (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not have a solution to the problem; just a few observations (which are too long for a comment, so I am posting them here).

First, when the problem talks about $B$ being a **collection** of subsets of $V$, this could either mean a **set** of subsets or a **"multiset"** of subsets of $V$. The latter is not uncommon in combinatorial design theory; however, the statement of the problem would be clearly false, so for now we chose to interpret **collection** as **set**.

Second, the seemingly two different cases in the problem ("one block that contains all the points" vs. "a design that has all the $k$-subsets of the set") can really be merged into one because the first case is simply a special case of the second one (with $v=k$).

So, now let's give the scenario a name and call a $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ design **rigid** if $v\le k+t$. Then the claim is that every rigid design is trivial.

The third observation is that it suffices to show the claim for designs with $v=k+t$ (we might call these **strongly rigid**) because then it follows for all rigid designs by induction over $t$.

Now in order to do this, let $D=(V,B)$ be a strongly rigid $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ design. Then $D$ is trivial if and only if $\lambda={k\choose t}$.

Now this is the point where things start to get interesting: I have tried to find a counterexample (by finding parameters for which we can choose $\lambda$ to be smaller than $k\choose t$), but haven't managed to find one. For example, consider the case $t=6, k=9, v=15$. Then in order for 
$$b=\lambda\cdot\frac{15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10}{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}=\lambda\cdot\frac{715}{12}$$
to be an integer, we could simply choose $\lambda=12$, but we also need to consider the number $b''$ of blocks in the second derivative $D''$ of $D$, and here
$$b''=\lambda\cdot\frac{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10}{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}=12\cdot\frac{143}{7}=\frac{1716}{7}$$
which is not an integer. So, in this example, $12$ is too small and we really need to choose $\lambda=7\cdot 12=84={k\choose t}$.

I have examined several sets of parameters like this, and they all end up with $\lambda={k\choose t}$ in one way or the other. On the other hand, I can't seem to find a systematic approach to a general proof. In the special cases of small values of $t$ (i.e. for $t\le3$), it can be shown with a few number theoretic arguments, but for larger values of $t$ (particularly for compound ones), the number and complexity of the case distinctions grows uncomfortably, so I really don't know how to go on at this point.

If anyone can shed some light on the situation, I'd be very grateful.

---

**Update, Feb-12-2018:**

Sometimes it is rewarding to consult the literature: I found a solution to your problem in Albrecht Beutelspacher's "Einführung in die endliche Geometrie I". The following is based on proposition 4.1.1:

Let $D=(V,B)$ be a $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ design with $t\ge2$, and let $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ be disjoint subsets of $V$ or orders $i$ and $j$, respectively, such that $i+j\le t$.
Then the number of blocks of $B$ that contain $\mathcal{I}$ and are disjoint from $\mathcal{J}$ is
$$b_{i,j}:=\lambda\cdot\frac{{v-i-j}\choose{k-i}}{{v-t}\choose{k-t}}.$$

In particular, the number $b_{i,j}$ does not depend on the choices of $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$, (or, in other words, designs do not only behave regularly with respect to vertex sets that are contained in their blocks, but also with respect to vertex sets that their blocks miss – at least as long as these vertex sets are small enough).

The proposition can relatively easily be shown by using induction on $j$.

The original claim then follows as a corollary: Let $D=(V,B)$ be a strongly rigid $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ design, i.e. $v=k+t$. Then the proposition yields that $b_{0,t}$ is positive, i.e. for any set $T$ of $t$ points of $V$, there exists a block $S$ of $B$ that completely misses $T$. But $|V\setminus T|=k$, so $S=V\setminus T$. But since $T$ was arbitrary, this means that every $k$-subset of $V$ is a block, i.e. $D$ is trivial.

Comment: The problem seems to be trivial, but the proof isn’t simple for me. Thank you for the answer!